# No resource found in web application using JSF

Tags: jsf, http-status-code-404

I started my first application using JSF, but i just can't manage to make my web application find my external resources(like index.xhtml). And I do not know why

-webapp
-- WEB-INF
--- web.xml
-- index.xhml

In web.xml I have the following line:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

But i always get a 404 the index.xhtml was not found.

Edit1: the issue was due to the fact that resulting war was not having resources like index.xhtml. Now when compiling, the war file contains everything inside the webapp folder. However I am unable to deploy to wildfly...

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"lab4.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
```

any idea why?

Comment: actually when building the war, the resources (index.xhtml, for example are not loaded/added. i just don't have them in the target folder

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to comment, but do not yet have enough points.

It's difficult to say what's causing the WFLYCTL0013 error, but I recommend reviewing the stack trace for the java.lang.NullPointerException.  Perhaps it's happening out of your application code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. The issue was that I was missing a dependency. Thanks

Comment: Answers should help other users, too. Please add which dependency it was.